# Jenkins use import in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins

How can I use `import` statements in `Jenkinsfile`?

This is the import statement:

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction
```

I want to use `AbstractTestResultAction` in a `script` section.

Comment: Please see similar problem described in that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39920437/how-to-access-junit-test-counts-in-jenkins-pipeline-project

Comment: Use import hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it that way - this what the `Jenkinsfile` looks like:

```
import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import hudson.tasks.test.AbstractTestResultAction;

@NonCPS
  def getTestSummary = { ->
    def testResultAction = currentBuild.rawBuild.getAction(AbstractTestResultAction.class)
    def summary = ""

    if (testResultAction != null) {
        def total = testResultAction.getTotalCount()
        def failed = testResultAction.getFailCount()
        def skipped = testResultAction.getSkipCount()

        summary = "Test results:\n\t"
        summary = summary + ("Passed: " + (total - failed - skipped))
        summary = summary + (", Failed: " + failed + " ${testResultAction.failureDiffString}")
        summary = summary + (", Skipped: " + skipped)
    } else {
        summary = "No tests found"
    }
    return summary
  }

pipeline {

    ... 

 post {
      always {
          script {
              def testSummaryRaw = getTestSummary()
              def testSummary = "`${testSummaryRaw}`"
              ...
          }
      }
    }

    ... 

}
```