# How to checkout shared library pipeline other then master

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

**My Jenkins master doesn't have an executor** and it can't have due to the design of Jenkins we have in our company. We have 2 worker node. When I add Pipeline shared library then by default Jenkins tries to checkout in master and fails due to obvious reasons as it can't find `git` as it is not available in Jenkins master.

```
Cloning repository git@github.com:Test/jenkins-pipeline-shared.git


> git init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/rp-pipe_PR-675@libs/slackNotify # timeout=10
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/rp-pipe_PR-675@libs/slackNotify
```

I don't understand why Jenkins can even try to checkout shared library in master because master doesn't even have an executor.

I looked at other people's opinion but my things stop at the point it tries to checkout. How can I get over this? I thought to keep my shared library groovy file in the same repo and import the library into JenkinsFile but seems like it is also not working for me. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800195/how-do-you-load-a-groovy-file-and-execute-it) but Jenkins couldn't identify `modules`

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 14: Expected a step @ line 14, column 17.
modules.sendNotifications = load "vars/sendNotifications.groovy"
```

I tried `libraryResource ('vars/sendNotifications.groovy')` but it's not working. Jenkins just fails without throwing any error.

**Solution which I think but don't know how to implement** :

1. Checkout pipeline library in the node where my job is suppose to run
2. Ignore pipeline library and create a groovy file in the same repo and import that in the JenkinsFile

Comment: The shared library will be checked out to your workspace depending upon your usage. If your workspace is on a worker node, then it will exist there.

Comment: I manage my node from the JenkinsFile. the checkout happens before it hits the `agent { label '!master' }` in the pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to acquire a worker first and then load the library from within:

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Init') {
      steps {
        library 'my-fancy-library'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now, I can see the checkout has been done in the worker node. Thanks but Still I get the same error - `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/rp-pipe_PR-675@libs/slackNotify"): error=2, No such file or directory`. I checked `which git` and I have git in the `PATH`. I don't know why it still complains

Comment: I noticed that the Jenkins attempts to checkout the library repo in `var/lib/` and which ofcourse it doesn't have a permission to do that. Why it doesn't attempt to clone the repo in the `/home/ec2-user/workspace` like other repo?

Comment: I think this is the workspace where your Jenkins runs.

Comment: Accepting the answer as indeed it solved my original question of checking out to a worker node.

Comment: yes, `/var/lib/` is the installation location but the workspace is `/home/ec2-user/workspace` and would expect git checkout over here as other that the shared library the git checkout is done in this directory.